# Debounce gets wrong argument value on execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

### The main question is how to execute `debounce` function with actual variable value instead of the value which was actual 500ms ago?

At execution time `debounce` function seems to be having outdated values of arguments because of a closure.

In my code I am trying to hide dropdown only if user leaves the mouse from dropdown for minimum as 1 second. So if user leaves the mouse from dropdown and then immediately enter the mouse back - dropdown will be still visible.

**But** `debounceHide` **function never sets active dropdown to** `null` **because it uses the** `stillHoverOnDropdown` **value which was actual 1000ms ago (so its value is `true`)**

I put the code below, but note that it's just for better understanding. My code on the actual project is much larger and there are a lot of links with dropdowns.

Also you will see `onHoverStart` and `onHoverEnd` - that's equal to `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.
Example:

```js
function debounce(fn, ms, ...args) {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}


const Navbar = () => {
  const [activeDropdown, setActiveDropdown] = useState(null);
  const [stillHoverOnDropdown, setStillHoverOnDropdown] = useState(false);

  const debounceHide = debounce(
    () => {
      if (!stillOnDropdown) {
        setActiveDropdown(null);
      }
    },
    1000
  );

  const handleHoverStart = () => {
    setStillOnDropdown(true)
  }

  const handleHoverEnd = () => {
    setStillOnDropdown(false)
    debounceHide();
  }

  return (
    <>
       <motion.a onHoverStart={() => handleDropdownHover(el.id)}>Link</motion.a>
       <motion.div onHoverStart={handleHoverStart} onHoverEnd={handleHoverEnd}>Dropdown Content</motion.div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on my question. When `setTimeout` is scheduled it's using the value of `stillOnDropdown` at the time it was scheduled.

`useRef` can solve that problem.

```js
// Use a ref to access the current count value in
// an async callback.
const countRef = useRef(count);
countRef.current = count;

const getCountTimeout = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setTimeoutCount(countRef.current);
  }, 2000);
};
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14010